# Updating a column for a list of items in Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I want to update a specific column against a list of items/rows in a table. 1 way is to apply a loop on the update method, but is there any way to pass list of items and update that column for all, instead of doing it in loop?

Dao method:

```
   @Query("UPDATE items SET is_processing=1 WHERE item_id=:id")
    public abstract void updateProcessingStatus(String id);
```

Current update code:

```
public void updateStatusOfList(List<Item> items)
{

   for(Item item:items)
   myDao.updateProcessingStatus(item);

}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just pass your list as a variable into the query:

```
@Query("UPDATE items SET is_processing=1 WHERE item_id in (:items) ")
public abstract void updateProcessingStatus(List<String> items);
```

You will probably need to create a String List from your Items list first.

Comment: What if I want to update different value for the same column for those rows?

Answer (score 2):

[live-love](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50662695)'s answer is not complete. As stated by Sam, you might need to use different columns:

```kotlin
@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun update(items: List<Attributes>)
```

where `items` are the updated objects (you might want to handle other column data by copying *outside* the dao call since db calls in loops impact runtime)